# Unable to determine time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

So I'm supposed to split the input string into 3 palindromic substrings. This is a solution which was given and although I understand it well, I'm having difficulty determining its time complexity. Here is the code:

```
    public static boolean isPallindrome(String str){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
        return str.equals(sb.reverse().toString());
    }

    public static void func(String s){
        for(int i = 1; i < s.length() - 2; i++){
            if (isPallindrome(s.substring(0, i))){
                for(int j = i+1; j < s.length(); j++){
                    if (isPallindrome(s.substring(i, j)) & isPallindrome(s.substring(j))){
                        System.out.print(s.substring(0, i).trim() + "\n" + s.substring(i, j).trim() + "\n" + s.substring(j, s.length()).trim());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the time complexity of the `func` function?

I think it'll be O(n^2) but I'm not so sure.

It'll be really helpful for a beginner like me if the time complexity of this function was properly explained. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think it is _O(n^2)_? Worst case is that input string is `n` times the same letter, e.g. `func("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")` has `n = 40` and *every* call to `isPallindrome()` in the code will return true. So if you think that code is only _O(n^2)_, you're not considering the time complexity of the `isPallindrome()` call, which is certainly ***not*** _O(1)_.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. Does that mean the time complexity will be O(n^3)?

Comment: More like _O(n^4)_, don't you think?

Comment: Oh, I see since there are multiple calls to ```isPallindrome()``` in 2 different loops. Is there any way I can decrease the time complexity? I am finding it hard to optimize.